# Remove the annotation box from the picture

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, data-annotations

**
What I want to do is remove the red box in 5000 images.
I wrote a piece of python code for one sample image, but I don't know where  got something wrong. I can't realize such purpose. I appreciate any other way to solve this problem.[This is the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyc7N.jpg)

[image]

**
'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\lenvov\Desktop\baowenti\2.jpg')
# 缩放
rows, cols, channels = img.shape
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# lower mask (0-10)
lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
# upper mask (170-180)
lower_red = np.array([170,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)    
# join my masks
mask = mask0+mask1
Index =  np.where(mask != 0)
pix_X = Index[0]
pix_Y = Index[1]    
for i in range(len(list(pix_X))):
    if i < 305:

        img[(pix_X[i], pix_Y[i])] = (1/4 * (img[(pix_X[i]+20, pix_Y[i]+4)] +
                                            img[(pix_X[i]+21, pix_Y[i]+2)] +
                                            img[(pix_X[i]+4, pix_Y[i]+20)] +
                                            img[(pix_X[i]+2, pix_Y[i]+21)])).round()

cv2.imshow('res', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

'''

Comment: Are your images only available in the JPEG format ? What is the purpose of removing the red box ? (This is important to know.)

Comment: I want to use it for training a deep learning based object detection model, I don' know whether it wil Affects the actual accuracy of the model using opencv inpaint function. But I think it may be the best way.

Comment: Are your images only available in the JPEG format ?

Comment: yes，they are all with the ‘.jpg’ suffix.

Comment: I mean, don't you have the uncompressed versions ?

Comment: Thanks. However, this is exactly what we want to do, repair images in jpg format.

Answer (score 4):

I am not certain what the problem is, but would suggest you replace the red box using *"inpainting"* - see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html)

That makes your code look like this:

```
...
...
# join my masks
mask = mask0+mask1

result = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]

---

As you have identified, the red hues wrap around and lie near 180 or 0 and, as a result you are running your range detection twice. One nifty *"trick"* you can use is to invert the image (by subtracting from 255) before conversion to HSV and then look for cyan colour (i.e. Hue=90 in OpenCV) instead of red. So your code becomes:

```
# Load image
img = cv2.imread('box.jpg') 

# Invert and convert to HSV
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(255-img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

# Mask all red pixels (cyan in inverted image)
lo = np.uint8([80,30,0]) 
hi = np.uint8([95,255,255])  

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv,lo,hi)

# Inpaint red box
result = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

---

Also, if you have 5,000 images to do, I would suggest you consider multiprocessing - there is an example you could use as a basis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621).

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, OpenCV, inpainting, cv2:inpaint.