# Is there a way to provide two ranges of Hue in cv2, or exclude a range?

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I'm working on my Masters Thesis on predicting coastal hydrodynamics and I've run into a slight hurdle.

My data includes "blobs" of pink dye near the coast, and in order for me to detect the blob properly with cv2 I am converting to HSV, where the pink hues are included at the lower and upper range of the spectrum. If I keep it completely open, then I get a lot more noise and other regions I'm not interested in.

Is there a way to include two different ranges of Hue values, or instead to exclude a range of Hue values for cv2.inRange?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You just use **OpenCV** `bitwise_and()` and `bitwise_or()` to combine the masks.

Comment: I feel silly for not thinking of just making two different masks. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another option, if it is the Reds that are upsetting you because they wrap around at 359 degrees, you can always invert your image and look for Cyans instead... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236916/2836621

Comment: This worked beautifully! I really appreciate the idea and info.