# Remove/Erase object from image using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to Remove/Erase an object from image which is highlighted with red color using opencv [image: Original Image]

I have achieved a bit closer result but it's just reducing the transparency of the object
[image: Result I have acheived] but i want it to make it completely invisible.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

input = sys.argv[1]

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(input)

# Define the color range of the object to be removed
lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 200])
upper_red = np.array([50, 50, 255])

# Create a mask that identifies the object to be removed
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_red, upper_red)

# Inpaint the object area using the TELEA algorithm
inpaint = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

# Save the inpainted image
cv2.imwrite(input, inpaint)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask may have problem on the edges, and not covering all red-ish pixels. You can dilated the mask:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

input = sys.argv[1]

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(input)

# Define the color range of the object to be removed
lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 150])
upper_red = np.array([100, 100, 255])

# Create a mask that identifies the object to be removed
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_red, upper_red)

# Inpaint the object area using the TELEA algorithm
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilated_mask = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
inpaint = cv2.inpaint(img, dilated_mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

# Save the inpainted image
cv2.imwrite('out_'+input, inpaint)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it increased the transparency

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat Does the updated code answer your question?

Comment: your code works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I am wondering how can i achieve the same output if my red color is rgba(255,0,0,0.5)  instead of pure red.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, intuitively I would think it's kind of ambiguous to tell if a pixel is white+50% red, or it is just pink without additional red highlight, thus just from the pixel color I cannot imagine how to decide if that pixel should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to save your mask as an image so you can check how well it is selecting your reds:

```
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)
```

---

Secondly, you will probably find it more accurate to locate highly saturated reds (and greens etc) in [HSL/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colourspace. So, have a look for other answers tagged [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) and containing "HSV". You'll need

```
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

and be aware that reds wrap around zero, because the hue wheel is cyclic. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236916/2836621).