# Delete Rasters that contain pixel values of Zero

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, geotiff

I have a working code that will iterate through a folder, identify and delete if a `.tif` only contains pixel values of all zero, hence a black image. The problem is that I have 12,000 images in the folder and it take quite a long time for the process to finish. I am wondering if there is a faster way I could do this?

```
from PIL import Image
import os


directory = 'D:/images/'
for image in os.listdir(directory):
    indiv = Image.open(directory + image)
    pixel_values = list(indiv.getdata())
    y = len(pixel_values)

    list_yes = []
    for RGBA in pixel_values:
        if RGBA == (0, 0, 0, 0):
            Black_image = 'yes'
            list_yes.append(Black_image)
            x = len(list_yes)
            if x == y:
                os.remove(directory + image)
```

**Output of black .tif:**

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
....
Like 400,000 more rows of this
```

Comment: Try `numpy.all(numpy.array(indiv) == 0)`. Should be a lot faster.

Comment: So in place of `all(pixels == (0, 0, 0, 0)` in @ScienceSnake answer?

Comment: Instead of `all(pixels == (0, 0, 0, 0) for pixels in list(indiv.getdata()))`.

Comment: @cgohlke Yes, that works much faster!

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for multiprocessing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Could you provide a link for me to understand how to do something like that?

Comment: Here's one that uses PIL but the idea is identical... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be substantially faster

```
directory = 'D:/images/'
for image in os.listdir(directory):
    indiv = Image.open(directory + image)
    if all(pixels == (0, 0, 0, 0) for pixels in list(indiv.getdata())):
        os.remove(directory + image)
```

I'm not sure the `list(...)` is needed either, I'm not too familiar with PIL. If it works without, removing it should cause another speedup.

Comment: I tried removing the `list(...)` before and it would print out `<ImagingCore object at 0x00000215AA411730>`. So I am not sure that I can take that out. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: Okay keep it in then, getdata() returns some different data type clearly. Do say if this works and if its measurably faster.

Comment: From what I can tell, it is removing the images faster. I would prefer faster, but beggars can't be choosers....