# Speed up the data extraction process from dicom files

Tags: python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, joblib

I am trying to extract images from Dicom files.

My folder structure is so below -

```
> BATCH 4       BATCH 6     BATCH 8     Batch 29    Batch 30-35 Batch 36    Batch 37-38_1
> BATCH 5       BATCH 7     BATCH 9     Batch 29_1  Batch 30-35_1   Batch 37-38
```

Each batch contains thousands of dicom images.
My broad approach is below -
I am storing all the batches in a single list `folder_list` and then iterating through all of the batches.
`single_files` contains every dicom file in each batch and then I am subsequently iterating through each file in a batch.
After checking few conditions on each file, I am extracting the image - `pixel_array` and moving it to desired location.
The issue is it is really slow and complexity is O(n^2) , is there a way to fasten it up.
Complete code-

```
from pydicom import pixel_data_handlers
counter = 0
Source_folder_path = '/Path/*/'
destination_dir = '/Volumes/My Book/Extracted_Dataset'
folder_list = glob.glob(Source_folder_path)
for folder_dir in folder_list:
    single_files = (glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_dir,'*')))
    final_destination = os.path.join(destination_dir, folder_dir.split('/')[-2])
    for i in single_files:
        print(i)
        dcm = pydicom.dcmread(i)
        name = dcm.PatientID
        dest = os.path.join(destination_dir,os.path.join(folder_dir,name))
        if dcm.PhotometricInterpretation == 'RGB':
            if dcm.Modality == "OP":
                if os.path.isdir(dest) == False:
                    os.mkdir(dest)
    
                img = dcm.pixel_array 
                name = dcm.PatientID+'_'+str(counter)+'.png'  
                counter+=1
                if dcm.LossyImageCompression:
                    if dcm.LossyImageCompression=='00':
                        img = pixel_data_handlers.util.convert_color_space(img, current = 'RGB', desired = 'YBR_FULL') 
                image_to_write = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder_dir,name),image_to_write)
                if not os.path.isdir(final_destination):
                    os.makedirs(final_destination)
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder_dir,name),final_destination)
                else:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder_dir,name),final_destination)
```

Modified version as per the suggestion,
CPU Utilisation is below - [image]

My IO utilisation is - [image]
Can it be speed up more -

```
def ProcessOne(f):
    """Function of main process."""
    counter = 0
    destination_dir = '/Volumes/My Book/Extracted_Dataset'
    folder_dir = f
    single_files = (glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_dir, '*')))
    final_destination = os.path.join(destination_dir, folder_dir.split('/')[-2])
    for i in single_files:
        print(i)
        dcm = pydicom.dcmread(i)
        name = dcm.PatientID
        dest = os.path.join(destination_dir, os.path.join(folder_dir, name))
        if dcm.PhotometricInterpretation == 'RGB':
            if dcm.Modality == "OP":
                if not os.path.isdir(dest):
                    os.mkdir(dest)
                img = dcm.pixel_array
                name = dcm.PatientID+'_'+str(counter)+'.png'
                counter += 1
                if dcm.LossyImageCompression:
                    if dcm.LossyImageCompression == '00':
                        img = pixel_data_handlers.util.convert_color_space(img, current='RGB', desired='YBR_FULL') # noqa
                image_to_write = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder_dir, name), image_to_write)
                if not os.path.isdir(final_destination):
                    os.makedirs(final_destination)
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder_dir, name), final_destination) # noqa
                else:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder_dir, name), final_destination) # noqa


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a pool of processes to check files
    p = Pool()

    # Create a list of files to process
    Source_folder_path = '/Path/*/' # noqa
    folder_list = glob.glob(Source_folder_path)
    print(f'Batches to process: {len(folder_list)}')

    # Map the list of files to check onto the Pool
    p.map(ProcessOne, folder_list)
```

Comment: Have a read of the second part of my answer here about using multiprocessing https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291332/2836621

Comment: Thank You @MarkSetchell, I updated the code as per your suggestion. Did I do it right? Can it be optimized further?

Comment: Was there a speed improvement with multiprocessing? Did you use your system's Performance Monitor to see if all CPU cores were kept busy and if you RAM and I/O were maxed out?

Comment: It is showing 82% of my CPU is idle. Also, I am not sure how accurately to read the activity monitor for each core.

Comment: Your CPU is expected to be mostly idle as this is an IO intensive program and no matter how you do it, there is a lot of IO waiting involved.

Comment: I also update the IO utilisation graph, is it optimum?

Comment: Your *"Data Written/second"* looks quite low. is your output data volume much less than your input data volume - I mean are you expecting to read a lot more than you write? Is your data on a decent speed disk (NVMe/SSD) or a slow USB2.0 external disk? Is the filesystem on your data disk HFS+/APFS or did you accidentally use a nasty Windows FAT32-formatted disk?

Comment: I expect the read and write volume to be equal as every file being read is being written. I am on a slow 3.0 (4Tb) Hard drive. File system is Mac os Extended, I did formatted the FAT32- Windows disk though, Is that wrong, How to do it the write way?

Comment: FAT-32 is horribly slow for writing on macOS. Personally I would use **Dusk Utility** to reformat as HFS+ but you need to make a backup first as that will lose everything on your disk.