# Batch image channel processing with pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-multiprocessing

I am quite new with `pillow` and `multiprocessing` and I am clearly missing something really basic here.
Briefly, I have a dataset of hunderds of images on a directory. I need to split each one into RGB channels, merge the green and blue channels (`ImageChops.add`) and save the output as a different image file.

Building from this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282882/batch-image-manipulation-with-pil), I haven't managed to get my code working, and I would be most grateful if you can point me in the right direction here:

```py
import platform
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool

print(platform.platform())
# macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit

def get_processed_im(f):
    im = Image.open(f)
    im_r, im_g, im_b = im.split()
    im_rf = ImageChops.add(im_g, im_b)
    # save images
    im_rf.save("RF_"+f, "JPEG")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a pool of processes to check files
    p = Pool()

    # Create a list of files to process
    files = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpeg")]

    print(f'Files to process: {len(files)}')
    
    print(files)

    p.map(get_processed_im, files)
```

Output:

```
Files to process: 4
['im1.jpeg', 'im2.jpeg', 'im3.jpeg', 'im4.jpeg']
```

There is no error message but the code chunk does not complete running after a long period of time waiting in a directory with only 4 files.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you forget to send a `path` to `glob.glob`?

Comment: Post the error you are receiving in the question as well

Comment: Thanks, I actually get the list of file names with ```glob.glob("*.jpeg")```. The chunk keeps running and I do not get an error message.

Comment: Try adding some print statements inside `get_processed_im` to find which line is blocking

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, I am on Mac.