How to run python subprocess with PIPE in parallel?
I'm converting a bunch of SVG images to PNG using inkscape.
Single threaded:

import subprocess
import time
import os

inkscape_path = r'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.com'

steps=30
filenames = []
processes = []

# t_start = time.process_time()
t_start = time.time()
for i in range(steps):
    template = bytes(f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-10 -10 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                   
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{i*9/(steps-1)+1}" y2="0" stroke="green"/>
    </svg>
    """,'UTF-8')

    filename = f'img{i:02}.png'
    filenames.append(filename)

    process = subprocess.run([inkscape_path, '-p', '-o', filename],input=template )

# elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t_start
elapsed_time = time.time() - t_start

print(elapsed_time)

This works and takes 85 seconds in total for 30 images.
If I try it with communicate() it waits for completion for each process. So I set timeout to 0 and ignore the raised exception.

import subprocess
import time
import os

inkscape_path = r'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.com'

steps=30
filenames = []
processes = []

# t_start = time.process_time()
t_start = time.time()
for i in range(steps):
    template = bytes(f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-10 -10 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                   
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{i*9/(steps-1)+1}" y2="0" stroke="green"/>
    </svg>
    """,'UTF-8')

    filename = f'img{i:02}.png'
    filenames.append(filename)

    process = subprocess.Popen([inkscape_path, '-p', '-o', filename],stdin= subprocess.PIPE, env=dict(os.environ, SELF_CALL="xxx") )

    try:
        process.communicate(template,timeout=0)
    except:
        pass
   
    processes.append(process)
    
for p in processes:
    p.wait()

# elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t_start
elapsed_time = time.time() - t_start

print(elapsed_time)

This works and takes 30 seconds, but I don't think this is a clean way to do it.
How do I run multiple of these subprocesses in parallel in a clean way. Preferably in 1 line.
(SELF_CALL is a workaround as inkscape sometimes throws exceptions when multiple instances are running)

How about using multiprocessing? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291332/2836621

Is there supposed to be a loop around the code in the second code block?

subprocess.Popen() should run them in parallel. I think this is a reasonably clean way to do it.

I replaced the loop by a comment. I could ad some simplified code if you want. Without the timeout set to 0 it takes longer than the non-parallel version.
