# load all jpg images from a folder using python

Tags: python, loops, file, image-processing

How can I apply my filter to all jpg images in a single folder after another.
A loop like check how many data then load pic1 (then filter and store result) going to load pic2...until pic.last
I´m using imread to load and imwrite to store after the filter for 1 image atm

i'm running an object search by using different color-filter options this works fine. I´m chemist and new to python.

Comment: most people use `os.walk` as a basis

Comment: Your title implies a single folder. Your question implies multiple folders. What OS are you using? Please share your latest/greatest code. Do you have many thousands of images and need performance? Or just a few dozen?

Comment: I´m currently using Anaconda on Win10 mashine. It is a single folder and there are usally about 50 to 500 images.

Comment: ok then, `os.listdir` or `glob.glob`. still, _not_ an image processing problem. you haven't got any images yet to process.

Comment: It's much the same as this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621