# Multiprocessing multi-layered image merging in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing

I've spent a few hours searching stack and google for an answer to this and seem to get close but never quite get the answer. I feel like it's something simple in `create_files` but I'm just not getting it.

I'm trying to increase the speed of a program that gets a random image from numbered folders, and stacks them on top of each other with transparency using Pillow. Now as soon as you hit 18 folders, with 20 or so images in each, this can be quite slow at around 2 seconds per image on my M1 MacBook Pro. I thought of using multiprocessing to speed things up, and I don't know if it's because my code is so reliant on for loop iterator variables, but I couldn't seem to get pool.map to work for me without differing errors. I'll post a snippet of the relevant functions. Any advice would be amazing, I'm sure it's a simple refactor, might still just be a bit too green with Python.

The variables that some of the functions call are either the path to a folder, or an array of all of the image paths (image1 will be [0] image2 will be [1] etc).

```
def save_file(img, counter):
    if not os.path.exists(f"{output_folder}"):
        os.makedirs(f"{output_folder}")
    img.save(f"{output_folder}/file_{counter}.png")


def create_composite(layer_count, img):
    image_size = Image.open(image_paths[0][0])
    composite_img = Image.new("RGBA", image_size.size)
    composite_img = merge_images(layer_count, img, composite_img)
    return composite_img


def merge_images(layer_count, img, composite_img):
    for i in range(layer_count):
        next_img = Image.open(img[i])
        composite_img = Image.alpha_composite(composite_img, next_img)
    return composite_img


def randomise_layers(layer_count):
    # Creates an array with randomised files for each layer and checks for exceptions.
    image_stack = []
    for i in range(layer_count):
        # Checks if there are any image conflicts and adds them to the stack.
        image_stack.append(check_exception(i))
    return image_stack


def check_exception(index):
    # Checks if any of the layers have a known exception with another layer
    temp_file_path = file_paths(index)
    if is_exception(temp_file_path):
        check_exception(index)
    else:
        return temp_file_path


def is_exception(file_path):
    # Gets layer exceptions from file
    return False


def create_files(iterations):
    for i in range(iterations):
        save_file(create_composite(layer_count, randomise_layers(layer_count)), i)
        if iterations < 10:
            print(f"File {i+1} created.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterations = 5
    create_files(iterations)
```

Comment: Take a look at ProcessPoolExecutor and its *map()* function. The map list would be *image_paths*. The code shown seems to process the same file 5 times. Is that the intention?

Comment: It's actually getting passed in new files per layer each time, so it's creating five files, each with randomly selected images per layer (the randomise_layers function). Will look into the ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: You say it slows down when you get to 20 folders with 20 files in each, but your code doesn't seem in the least dependent on the number of folders or how many files in each. Any explanations? You don't load all the images somewhere and fill your RAM do you? Have you tried looking at *"memory"* demand in your system's *"Activity Monitor"* to see if more files, or more directories means more RAM demand?

Comment: Also, what are the approximate height and width of your images in pixels? And ultimately how many output files do you want to produce?

Comment: Initially I load the list of folders and images into arrays (images are 2d indexed to the folder index). From there, it creates a blank image, opens up one random image from the first folder (via the array) and merges them together, then it rinses and repeats for each folder (this should mean only 2-3 images are loaded into ram at once). Once all folders have been done, it then saves the file. Then the process starts again for each new randomised file. I've omitted some of the code that sets that up before creation.

Does that help clarify? May have discovered a solution I'll post too.

Comment: Images are 2500x2500 PNGs, theoretically up to thousands, though likely less than 10s of thousands (thus the wanting to make it faster than one per 2 seconds).

Helping my sister, who is an artist, on some art projects.

Comment: This answer might give you an idea for multiprocessing... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621

Comment: nobody suggested to **profile the code** yet so there. you need to know where time is spent before you can attack the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK! So thanks to Albert's suggestion, I looked more into ProcessPoolExecutor, and did some refactoring.

my `create_files` function is now as follows:

```
def create_files(iterations):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(os.cpu_count()-2) as exe:
        exe.map(save_file, list(range(iterations)))
```

Due to this refactoring and using map, I've had to move a bunch of variables to be global variables as I couldn't pass them into the functions onces the multiprocessing kicked in (seems to not hold onto any that have been declared in the same scope before). I'll look more into passing some of those values into the threads, another alternative would be to make lists of those variables, and do something like

```
var1 = [missing_variable] * iterations
```

to make them available.